# The article question (~for past mistakes ~)

Tags: past-tense

I read this article In Los angles times.

> "I am one of nearly 3,000 people in San Quentin State Prison who are
> **paying for past** mistakes."

I thought it has to be ~who are paying for **THE** past mistakes
Don't we need the in front of past mistakes?

THanks!

Comment: First, it's **Los Angeles**, not **Los angles**. Second, you need a period (.) when you end a sentence. Finally, [please don't say thanks in your post, it's nothing but noise](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). Please edit your post to remove it and fix the problems I mentioned, thanks!!!

Comment: Sorry but I can't help you edit it - I've reached my edit limit.

Answer (score 3):

> "I am one of nearly 3,000 people in San Quentin State Prison who are
> paying for past mistake**s**."

That is 100% correct.

General statements use plural nouns without a determiner.

- He really loves apple**s**.

To use the, it would have to be: paying for *the past mistakes of others.*

There, it is specific and would take "the".